# Secure C# Assemblies from unauthorized Callers

Tags: c#, security, assemblies

Is there any way to secure your assembly down to the class/property & class/method level to prevent the using/calling of them from another assembly that isn't signed by our company?

I would like to do this without any requirements on strong naming (like using StrongNameIdentityPermission) and stick with how an assembly is signed.  I really do not want to resort to using the InternalsVisibleTo attribute as that is not maintainable in a ever changing software ecosystem.

For example:

**Scenario One**

Foo.dll is signed by my company and Bar.dll is not signed at all.

Foo has Class A
Bar has Class B

Class A has public method GetSomething()
Class B tries to call Foo.A.GetSomething() and is rejected

Rejected can be an exception or being ignored in someway

**Scenario Two**

Foo.dll is signed by my company and Moo.dll is also signed by my company.

Foo has Class A
Moo has Class C

Class A has public method GetSomething()
Class C tries to call Foo.A.GetSomething() and is not rejected

Comment: Explain "signed". You specifically called out not strong naming so you're not talking about the Signing option available in .NET (because that is strong naming). Are you instead indicating authenticode signing?

Comment: Signed but not strong named, Strong Naming is signing and more.  So if you have a Verisign cert you can use it to sign a DLL, EXE, or whatever.

Comment: Right, so authenticode signing then via a code signing certificate?

Comment: Using a signing certificate from an authority yes.

Comment: Yeah, that's called Authenticode. It's useful to avoid the word "signing" because VS.NET uses that term to mean both.

Comment: And see below, there is a CAS permission for authenticode digital signatures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are wanting to limit the callers to only code that has been authenticode signed by a specific certificate, you can still use CAS (just not StrongNameIdentityPermission).

Use [PublisherIdentityPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.publisheridentitypermission.aspx) just like you would have used any CAS permissions. Or if you want to do it declaratively, [use an attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.publisheridentitypermissionattribute.aspx).

Comment: thanks, I will dig into this. It looks like it could solve the problem at my first glance.

Comment: Can you please publish code example ?(http://pastebin.com/ or any codehosting can help)

Comment: Per MSDN, this solution is no longer valid as of .NET 4.0.  Identity based permissions are no longer enforced by the framework.

Answer (score 6):

Obviously you have to perform a check on every call from within the called method - any external system trying to enforce the restrictions is easily bypassed using reflection.

From within the method you can use

```
new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Module.Assembly
```

to get the calling assembly. Now you can use

```
callingAssembly.GetName().GetPublicKey()
```

to obtain the public key of the calling assembly and compare it with the public key of the called assembly. If they match - assuming all your assemblies are signed with the same key pair - the caller is accepted as a legitimated caller.

But there is one loop hole - a 3rd party assembly can be delay signed with your companies public key and excluded from the digital signature verification. In consequence the loader will load the 3rd party assembly with a strong name and your companies public key even if it is not yet signed. To close this loop hole you have to check the signature. There is no managed API and you have to P/Invoke

```
Boolean StrongNameSignatureVerificationEx(
   String wszFilePath,
   Boolean fForceVerification,
   ref Boolean  pfWasVerified)
```

with `fForceVerification` set to `true` and check if the result is `true`.

All together this may be quite a lot overhead per call. The temptation is probably to cache the result but assuming a caller with reflection permission it is probably not very hard to manipulate such a cache. On the other hand you will never be 100% sure. Who ever controls the system is free to do (almost) everything he wants - attach an debugger, modify memory content, manipulate libraries or the whole runtime. Finally you have to efficiently protect your assembly from decompilation and modification, too.

Comment: With regards to this check: new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Module.Assembly,
shouldn't we check the assemblies all the way up the stack trace? Otherwise there could be an intermediary assembly (or calling application) which belongs to the attacker.

Comment: If you perform the check in every method (and property), you will always catch an unauthorized caller when he first attempts to call into the protected code - there is no need to walk the stack.

Comment: It might not be 100% possible to protect but one may make it harder for a moderate user to use it. what about solutions like https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-trial-using-managed.html and https://www.eziriz.com/dotnet_reactor.htm?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen DLL's written by companies (most notably Pegasus Imaging) that use a challenge/response system to unlock the assembly.  The purchaser of the DLL is provided with a "License Code," tied to the name of the purchaser, which the consumer of the DLL then uses to unlock a specific subset of the DLL's features.

So when the assembly is used the first time by the application, the `Unlock()` method is called in the assembly.  The user name and unlock code are passed in and run through an algorithm that verifies identity, presumably using a Public Key Encryption algorithm of some sort.

There are some bits encoded in the unlock code that specify features; these bits then set some feature flags in the assembly.  All calling functions must check these flags to determine if the appropriate feature is enabled.  The `Unlock()` method is called only once, and is good for the lifetime of the loaded assembly.

Of course, since you have to provide the "private key" in the assembly, this procedure is not hack-proof (what is?), but it is reasonably secure, and will keep the honest people honest.

Comment: I can of course write my own little framework that EVERY method in an assembly that I need to secure would call a bool:Verify() method or something before allowing it to proceed to do what it is supposed to do.  However I am looking for something that I hope is part of the .Net Framework and can be added to the AssemblyInfo, basically something more global that would deal with the secure work at compile time.

Comment: Excellent. I've been casting around for summat like this for a while. Why is thier not more of this type of security detail on the web.

Comment: @Creepy Gnome: You don't need to write your own framework for that, that's what AOP is for.

Comment: There is, but the way Microsoft wants you to do this type of thing is really with StrongNameIdentityPermission requiring you to use their Strong-Name concept, and this will work very nice.  However, we are not in a place where we can use Strong-Names yet, so I was looking to see if there is any other realistic global option that can just using the plain jane signing of a DLL or EXE to do something similar.

Comment: @R0MANARMY how do aspects help with this situation?

Comment: @Creepy Gnome: You could look at using PostSharp to automatically add the Verify() call to all your methods if the sandbox AppDomain solution doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: @Creepy Gnome: Even StrongNameIdentityPermissionAttribute doesn't prevent fully trusted code from calling your assembly, whatever its strong name is (per the MSDN documentation).

Comment: @Creepy Gnome: Checking security settings in a consistent matter across multiple method calls seems like a very good example of cross-cutting of concerns.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as you realize, it's not enough to use `InternalsVisibleTo` - you would also need to sign and strongly-name each assembly to ensure someone can't just spoof the name.

Now that that's out of the way, you would have to develop a challenge-response implementation on your own - this isn't something you can do unless you're willing to use the `InternalsVisibleTo` approach that you explicitly describe you don't want to use.

In a C-R model, you would need to pass some kind of token with every method call (or perhaps just to instantiate an object). The token would be a class that only your code can create an instance of - I would make this an internal class of the assembly you want to consume and make it accessible with `InternalsVisibleTo` - this way only a single class needs to be managed:

```
// SharedAssembly.dll
// marks ConsumingAssembly.dll as having access to internals...

internal sealed class AccessToken { }

public class SecuredClass
{
   public static bool WorkMethod( AccessToken token, string otherParameter )
   {
       if( token == null )
           throw new ArgumentException(); // you may want a custom exception.

       // do your business logic...
       return true;        
   }
}



// ConsumingAssembly.dll  (has access via InternalsVisibleTo)

public class MainClass
{
  public static void Main()
  {
      var token = new AccessToken(); // can create this because of IVT access
      SecuredClass.WorkMethod( token, "" );  // tada...
  }
}
```

You may want to put the `AccessToken` class in a third assembly that both the service provider and consumer know about so that you don't have to constantly maintain a different group for access token classes for different assemblies.

Building a C-R mechanism for every method is cumbersome and tedious. It also isn't 100% foolproof - someone with enough time and patience could probably find a way around it.

The best option (which may or may not be possible in your case) would be to keep your private code on your own servers and only expose it as a webservice (or something similar). This allows you to actively manage accessiblity to your IP and allows you to update who has access in a centralized (rather than distributed) manner. Technologies already exist to restrict access to web services using certificates, message-signature, and encryption. This would be the most reliable (and proven) way to control access to you IP.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's too much fuss for nothing! If you really want security, put your code behind a server and use a client-server architecture. Or web services. Or something in between like WCF, or remoting. Then use authentication to authenticate a client.

Heck you can make everything private, expose a public API and root the calls locally.

Securing a dll from unauthorized callers in a desktop only environment only makes matters more complicated and harder to work with. Not to mention that it would look pretty ugly on the inside.

I see some conventions emerging. And that may work for you. But it doesn't give you the "total security" you require. If you have an assembly that is supposed to be hidden from customers, don't put it in the GAC. Use namespaces postfixed with something like "INTERNAL".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do this if you don't control the execution environment under which the code is run.  Code running with full trust on a user's machine would be able to get around any restrictions you added.  For example, full trust code could invoke private or internal methods with the reflection APIs, so even using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute wouldn't work.

If you control the execution environment, you can create an AppDomain where your code is fully trusted, and third party code is partially trusted and can't call your code unless you put an [AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.allowpartiallytrustedcallersattribute.aspx) (APTCA) on the assembly.  You can restrict which methods can be called in an APTCA assembly with the [SecurityCritical](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securitycriticalattribute.aspx) and [SecuritySafeCritical](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securitysafecriticalattribute.aspx) attributes.

[How to: Run Partially Trusted Code in a Sandbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046.aspx)

Comment: It might not be 100% possible to protect but one may make it harder for a moderate user to use it. what about solutions like https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-trial-using-managed.html and https://www.eziriz.com/dotnet_reactor.htm