# How to secure the MVC4 ASP.NET and WCF dll?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-4, wcf-security

I have a project that has a WCF service project and MVC project which contains everything of MVC in my solution. I would like to know how to secure this dll as I would be exposing it or sharing this to some team, where my client asked me to secure these DLLs.

I thought of dotfuscator as one example, just read in a site, but no clarity.

Secondly, someone said I can use strong name key in VS (But I am not satisfied that, strong name is for securing, but for making the DLL unique, correct? )

Please help me clarify the above two questions and also the guidance for securing the DLLs

Answer (score 0):

Check these links which have the same issue as yours.

[Protect C# DLL from third party](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109761/protect-c-sharp-dll-from-third-party)

[How to protect dlls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805461/how-to-protect-dlls)

[how to secure dll functions from being used outside of my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999830/how-to-secure-dll-functions-from-being-used-outside-of-my-application)

[Secure C# Assemblies from unauthorized Callers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806842/secure-c-sharp-assemblies-from-unauthorized-callers)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/28111aa6-e080-471b-bec3-03876ab0c5cd/how-to-protect-c-dlls-from-reflector-or-disassembler